# Retrieve data from the nested table in webpage using python BeautifulSoup or lxml

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to retrieve data which is present in the table from the url : https://www.infogreffe.com/recherche-entreprise-dirigeants/resultats-entreprise-dirigeants.html?ga_cat=globale&ga_q=IMERYS#phrase=IMERYS

As i observed the data present in the inner HTML table.
I have tried the:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.infogreffe.com/recherche-entreprise-dirigeants/resultats-entreprise-dirigeants.html?ga_cat=globale&ga_q=IMERYS#phrase=IMERYS'
r = requests.get(url)
res = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')

data = []
table = soup.find_all(class_= 'dojoxGrid')
try:
    table_body = table.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
except:
    print("")


print(data)
```

but it returns nothing. Please help to get data from the table and their logic.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: When I try to get the url (copy/past in web browser), I get an error and no results

Comment: Try this url : (https://www.infogreffe.com) once the page got loaded in the search box: Enter "IMERYS"  and click on search icon

Comment: Yes, thats what I've done, but your python script may have the same problem...

Comment: Can you correct me where i have gone wrong???

Comment: It's not because of you, It is due to the website. If you want to be able to cope with JS, you should have a look at Selenium